# how to create docker entrypoint with parameters

Tags: docker

I met a really headache for this issue and almost pull my hair up and still can not resolve it.
I want docker image to start automatically whenever I start it, so I came to using entrypoint, but always failed.

This is command I usually use to start my app:

cd /opt/path
./start.sh -l dev -ssl false -srv api

I now want to run this command automatically when docker get started.

I used this in docker file:

```
WORKDIR /opt/ngcsc
ENTRYPOINT ["start.sh","-l","kubstaging","-ssl", "false", "-srv", "api"]
```

I got this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "start.sh": executable file not found in $PATH.
```

But if I change to absolute path:

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/ngcsc/start.sh","-l","kubstaging","-ssl", "false", "-srv", "api"]

after I run docker run image

I got:

```
standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

This is really a big problem and I googled a lot, nothing worked. can you help to tell me what to do?

Thanks

Comment: is your `/opt/ngcsc/start.sh` executable?

Comment: yes, for sure. if I do not use entryPoint, I can execute it inside with no problem

Answer (score 4):

Unix is looking for an executable binary to exec, not a shell script. To run the shell script, call it with the appropriate shell, e.g.:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/opt/ngcsc/start.sh","-l","kubstaging","-ssl", "false", "-srv", "api"]
```

Note that this won't make docker automatically start your container when the host reboots. For that, you want the `--restart` flag on `docker run`, e.g.:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped -itd your_image
```

Answer (score 1):

How about entering your command into a file and run that file with CMD?
For example:

```
# start.sh
cd /opt/path ./start.sh -l dev -ssl false -srv api

# Dockerfile
# ... other commands
COPY start.sh /usr/local/bin/start/sh
CMD start.sh
```

`start.sh` should be in the same path as the Dockerfile and should be executable.